# Virtual Directories not showing in IIS? (Visual Studio Application)

Tags: iis, appfabric, virtual-directory

I'm attempting to do a second part of a tutorial here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729689.aspx I'm following the instructions in that I have the OrderServiceProject creating a virtual directory here `http://localhost:8087/OrderService`.  From what I'm seeing, it should be creating successfully, but the OrderService virtual directory doesn't seem to exist according to iis.

I'm completely new to interacting with iis and would appreciate any assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the Web tab in the project properties.

Select your local web servern enter the project url and click on "Create Virtual Directory".
[image]

*Important Note* : Your local IIS server have to be started and binded to port 80. local IIS server **is not** IIS Express or Visual Studio Web Dev Server.

To open the IIS Manager, run InetMgr in the start menu.

Comment: I made it port 8087 because it says it's unable to create the virtual directory at 80 since it's already mapped to a different folder on an iis site.

Comment: Nevermind I just caught that it is not iis express.  I had that option checked, created it now successfully.  Now checking if it shows on iis.  And there it is under default web site.  You are awesome, thanks so much!